# Seguir o princípio OCP ou usar "instanceof"

Tags: classes, solid, princípios-de-programação

O princípio OCP prega: "aberto para extensão, mas fechado para alteração". Para conseguir isso precisamos abstrair, pois com uma abstração podemos estender sem precisar alterar aquele que usa a abstração.

Considere um exemplo didático:

[image: ocp]

A ideia é que eu posso estender o projeto adicionando novas letras sem, no entanto, precisar alterar a classe `Palavra`.

Até aí, tudo certo: abstração, polimorfismo, OCP.

Mas, se eu precisar saber a quantidade de determinadas letras, a quantidade de letra A, B, etc.?

Uma das formas de fazer isso é usando `instanceof`. Mas dessa forma, estarei violando o OCP, pois a cada adição de uma letra, terei que alterar a classe Palavra para acrescentar mais um `if` e `instanceof` pra contar a quantidade daquela letra.

Enfim, as questões são:

- existe um forma de evitar isso?
- a necessidade de saber especificamente sobre um objeto descaracteriza a adoção dessa abstração, ou seja, já que eu preciso saber sobre o objeto, não tenho que abstrair esse objeto?
- uso abstração num sentido, mas, inevitavelmente, concretizo, especifico (contrário de abstrair) num outro sentido?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Comment: Acho que o Princípio de Segregação de Interface (ISP) pode te ajudar um pouco.

Answer (score 2):

Tem algumas soluções.

1. Uma delas é o violar o OCP. Quem disse que ele é inviolável? Existe um motivo para ele existir, mas não é para segui-lo a qualquer custo. Esta costuma ser a solução mais simples e resolve bem em quase todos os casos. Se precisa da classe conhecer suas derivadas por alguma razão, faça. Evite, veja se não pode fazer de outra forma, mas pode fazer se entender as consequências.

   Linguagens modernas tem criado mecanismos próprios que violam muitas dessas regras que criaram, por que acha que estão fazendo isto? Acha que estão errando ou depois de tempo pra avaliar esses regras consideraram que elas não eram tão importantes assim? Claro tudo tem que ser analisado, não quer dizer que a regra não deva ser usada nunca.
2. Uma outra é criar um sistema de registro de classes derivadas. Pode ser feito até mesmo na classe base. Quando faz isso cria um dinamismo no código, então em vez de ter que mudar classe passa mudar o dado em tempo de execução, assim não precisa mexer na classe quando há uma nova derivada.

   Para fazer isto precisa ter um mecanismo, provavelmente com um dicionário na classe base e algo que permita registrar a classe nesse dicionário, aí a classe base tem ciência das classes derivadas em tempo de execução e pode consultá-las como quiser.

   Provavelmente a classe base tem pelo menos um método que já seja o mecanismo de registro da classe derivada nesse dicionário e todas derivadas terão isso e se fizer certo acaba forçando o registro sempre.

   Eu não faria isso em quase caso algum, eu não gosto de ir contra a filosofia da linguagem para seguir uma regra, com o detalhe que este mecanismo pode causar mais problemas. Eu vejo muito isso. Se a linguagem for dinâmica não é tão ruim assim, mas acho uma solução complexa para resolver um pro9belma que não existe se não seguir uma regra que em geral a pessoa nem sabe porque está fazendo aquilo.
3. Não vou falar de todas soluções, mas uma outra é usar reflexão, se estiver disponível, para identificar todas classes que derivam dessa base em toda aplicação e poder fazer a contagem que deseja. Novamente acho uma solução ruim para a maioria dos casos. Se for para insistir muito nisso eu optaria por um gerador de código que faz o mesmo que a reflexão, mas em tempo de compilação, deixando mais rápido e robusto, resolvendo o OCP sem ter nada adicional, mas admito que não é simples fazer para a maioria das pessoas.

Comment: Eu resolveria do primeiro jeito, na verdade fiz algo parecido para guardar os componentes visuais de uma aplicação Swing e mexer no tamanho das suas fontes de maneira uniforme. Usei `WeakReference` no mapeamento chave-valor e até que funcionou bem. Só não está automático, ou seja, cada árvore de componentes nova precisa ser adicionada manualmente ao mapa, isso é sujeito a erros. Se fosse automático ficaria uma solução bem melhor.

Comment: Ah, a remoção também é manual (digo, programática).

Comment: Quis dizer do segundo jeito